# How to delete directory if it contains specific file type in linux?

Tags: shell

How can I remove a directory if it contains only a specific file type (it should not contain any other files)?
For Example:

My Directory name is : `AAA`

`AAA` is contains a file `abc.txt`

In this case `AAA` should be deleted.

But if `AAA` contains `abc.txt` and `def.pdf` then in this case it should not be deleted.

Comment: Using `bash` or any script language is good for you?

Comment: You should start by trying something. Like writing a shell script that uses `ls`, pipe and `grep`, and that tests the result of these commands. Should you have a specific problem when testing it let us know.

Comment: If you combine bash and find I think you can find a way to do it.

Comment: It is easy if you can change question to: want remove all _files_ `abc.txt` and after want delete all remaining directories what are _empty_. Otherwise, you need one more step to check the file-count in the directory.

Comment: The question is if this is recursive or not. And you should tell in what encapsulation method you want to have it. Good luck with the homework.

Answer (score 0):

In every case, you need find the directories containg file `abc.txt`. For this you can use the file command, like:

```
find $topdir -name abc.txt -print
```

this will print the full pathname of the files. Stripping the `file` part, you will get a directory name. For this exists the `dirname` command what for the:

```
dirname "./x/y/z/abc.txt"
```

produces

```
./x/y/z
```

or you can use the `-printf` functionality of the `find` command to print only the directory part, like:

```
find $topdir -name abc.txt -printf "%h\n"
```

Because the filenames can contain spaces and or newlines too, it is recommended to use `null terminated` strings. E.g. the above command could be

```
find $topdir -name abc.txt -printf "%h\0" #null terminated
```

The result of any command could be read in the `while` loop, for the `null terminated` strings use:

```
while read -d $'\0' -r line
do
    #do something here
done < <(command)
```

The `find` command knows the `-empty` argument, what can help to find empty directories, or you can test the existence of any file with the

```
if [[ -f "$filename" ]]
then
    # do something
else
    # do something other
fi
```

or shortened

```
[[ -f "$filename ]] && dosomething
```

And finally you can remove a directory with the `rmdir` command or can recursively remove anything with the `rm -r` command. (dangerous!).

Now, you have probably all informations to make a script. Try create something and come back to ask if you meet some problems.